# Why a .Union() changes the order of the items?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [.Union() changes the order of the items?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12515926/union-changes-the-order-of-the-items)

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12515926/union-changes-the-order-of-the-items) question (without scenario/example; you should remove it, I can't) this is my problem :

I've noticed that if I do a `Union`, than an `Intersect` between collections `Attachment[]`, the order of the Items "can" change.

This is my code :

```
    GalleryDataClassesDataContext db = new GalleryDataClassesDataContext();
    List<Attachment> Allegati = db.ExecuteQuery<Attachment>("EXEC SelectAttachmentsByKey @Key={0}, @IDCliente={1}", new object[] { "", "47" }).ToList();
    List<Attachment> AllegatiPerCategorie = new List<Attachment>();

    AllegatiPerCategorie = AllegatiPerCategorie.Union(db.AttachmentAttachmentCategories.Where(aac => aac.IDAttachmentCategory == 72).OrderBy(p => p.Ordine == null ? 1 : 0).ThenBy(p => p.Ordine).Select(aac => aac.Attachment)).ToList();
    Allegati = Allegati.Intersect(AllegatiPerCategorie).ToList();

    count = 0;
    foreach (Attachment a in AllegatiPerCategorie)
    {
        Response.Write(count.ToString() + " - " + a.IDAttachment + "<br />");
        count++;
    }

    Response.Write("<br />### FILTERED ###<br /><br />");

    count = 0;
    foreach (Attachment a in Allegati)
    {
        Response.Write(count.ToString() + " - " + a.IDAttachment + "<br />");
        count++;
    }
```

And the output is :

```
0 - 6769
1 - 6792
2 - 6771
3 - 6699
4 - 6632
5 - 6774
6 - 6595
7 - 6602
8 - 6641
9 - 6643
10 - 6764
11 - 6634
12 - 6642
13 - 6660
14 - 6640
15 - 6665
16 - 6673
17 - 6767
18 - 6772
19 - 6766
20 - 6763
21 - 6768
22 - 6644
23 - 6635
24 - 6633
25 - 6793
26 - 6677
27 - 6608
28 - 6610
29 - 6558
30 - 6563
31 - 6631
32 - 6604
33 - 6606
34 - 6607
35 - 6596
36 - 6597
37 - 6598
38 - 6599
39 - 6600
40 - 6471
41 - 6470
42 - 6469
43 - 6601
44 - 6603
45 - 6663
46 - 6664
47 - 6645
48 - 6637
49 - 6638
50 - 6609
51 - 6611
52 - 6612
53 - 6613
54 - 6614
55 - 6615
56 - 6616
57 - 6617
58 - 6618
59 - 6619
60 - 6620
61 - 6622
62 - 6567
63 - 6568
64 - 6569
65 - 6570
66 - 6571
67 - 6572
68 - 6573
69 - 6575
70 - 6576
71 - 6577
72 - 6579
73 - 6580
74 - 6581
75 - 6582
76 - 6583
77 - 6584
78 - 6585
79 - 6586
80 - 6587
81 - 6588
82 - 6589
83 - 6590
84 - 6591
85 - 6592
86 - 6593
87 - 6594
88 - 6765

### FILTERED ###

0 - 6769
1 - 6792
2 - 6771
3 - 6699
4 - 6774
5 - 6595
6 - 6602
7 - 6634
8 - 6642
9 - 6640
10 - 6660
11 - 6665
12 - 6673
13 - 6772
14 - 6766
15 - 6768
16 - 6644
17 - 6635
18 - 6633
19 - 6793
20 - 6677
```

Well, notice for example the order of values **6660** and **6640** in the `AllegatiPerCategorie` list : **6660** before **6640** (at position *13* and *14*).

Now, watch at the same values order on `Allegati` : **6640** is before **6660** (at position *9* and *10*).

Why this behaviour? How can I fix it? Thank you

Comment: No, don't close this! Close the other! Here I have the example please!!!

Comment: @markzzz - you have an example? Great, then go to your other question, and make use of the `edit` link...

Comment: Please post the content of `AllegatiPerCategorie` (before the union), the `Union()`-argument and the result.

Comment: Damn you are right! If i browse Allegati first, 6640 is before 6660... how is possible? On the stored procedure 6660 is before 6640...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341731.aspx) states:

> When the object returned by this method is enumerated, Union enumerates first and second in that order and yields each element that has not already been yielded.

Here is a short example to demonstrate the behavior:

```
new int[] {1}.Union(new int[] {1, 2, 3}) // returns: 1,2,3
new int[] {2}.Union(new int[] {1, 2, 3}) // returns: 2,1,3
new int[] {3}.Union(new int[] {1, 2, 3}) // returns: 3,1,2

new int[] {1,3,5}.Union(new int[] {2, 4}) // returns: 1,3,5,2,4
```

Comment: +1 easy to understand, nice samples.

Answer (score 0):

[Union](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341731.aspx):

> Produces the **set** union of two sequences by using the default equality comparer.

A set by definition contains no duplicates and has no inherent sorting.

Also:

> This method excludes duplicates from the return set. This is different behavior to the `Concat<TSource>` method, which returns all the elements in the input sequences including duplicates.

And:

> When the object returned by this method is enumerated, Union enumerates first and second in that order and yields each element that has not already been yielded.

Comment: Yeah, but in fact it doesnt! According to the spec, it should "keep" the order from first list, than the second...

Comment: @markzzz - The spec says that the lists will be enumerated one after the other (the first, then the second). It does not say that each list will be enumerated in any specific order internally.

Comment: No, ok, but if in the first list 6660 is before 6640, after the order MUST be the same :O

Comment: @markzzz - No. You are misreading. If `6660` is in the first list and `6640` in the second, then the order will be as you expect (in that values in the first list will display before values in the second). There is no guarantee that the order of iteration in the first list (or the second) will be the original one.